# How to not choose the same value from two variables using an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick

I'm trying to create a very simple bingo game using an onclick event.

At the moment I'm using two variables, one for letters and one for numbers, which then collates into one new variable and is displayed on the page.

Is it possible to add this value to another variable and then an if..else.. function checks to see if the combination has been called already and if so, it will choose a different combination all on an onclick event?

```
<button onclick="myForEach();"> Click me </button>
```

Below is the js code I'm using at the moment:

```
function myForEach(){

/*letter variable and get a letter*/
    var letters = ["A", "B", "D", "E", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "N", "O", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"];
    getLetter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    /*number variable and get a number*/
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    getNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    /*call bingo*/
    bingo = getLetter + getNumber

/*display value*/
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = bingo;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

I haven't tried anything yet as I'm not sure if this is even possible and I'm not very good with JS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you can store bingo value in a an array, for each new bingo value you test if it's in array.

```js
let arBingo = [];

function myForEach() {
  /*letter variable and get a letter*/
  var letters = ["A", "B", "D", "E", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "N", "O", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"];
  getLetter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  /*number variable and get a number*/
  numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
  getNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  /*call bingo*/
  bingo = getLetter + getNumber

  /*display value*/
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = bingo;
  if (!arBingo.includes(bingo)) {
    arBingo.push(bingo);
  }
  console.log(arBingo);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<button onclick="myForEach();"> Click me </button>
```